# how i can play a sound in android studio and maket looping

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

**I've** been Stuck a Day trying to Play a sound in android studio and Making It looping any advice
why is hard to get your question proved by stackoverflow .

Comment: Everyone who posts here is just giving up a bit of their time to help people - if you want help or advice, you're more likely to get it if you post some details about what you've done, so people can easily tell you where you're going wrong. If you just post "I'm stuck can't do a thing" it'll get ignored, because what do you expect? You've gotta put some effort in otherwise why would anyone else

Comment: Like try typing "android play looping sound" into the search box at the top, someone's already answered this question in detail in the top result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask